# ReactiveX PublishProcessor doesn't execute onNext after onError?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I've to do pagination using `PublishProcessor`. So I fetch first set of data then turning off the network and trying to fetch another set. `onError` is invoking first time as there is no network, henceforward `onNext` doesn't invoke as a result I'm no more able to fetch next set of data when I back online. I just wanted to keep the subscription alive.

**Presenter Class**

```
   // Product pagination
    private final PublishProcessor<ProductRequest> mPagination;
    private int mPageNumber;
    private boolean mIsProductsLoading = false;
    private final int FETCH_ROW_COUNT = 10;

    /**
     * Dagger strictly enforces that arguments not marked with {@code @Nullable} are not injected
     * with {@code @Nullable} values.
     */
    @Inject
    ProductPresenter(Intent intent, Service service, SharedPrefsHelper sharedPrefsHelper) {
        mSubscriptions = new CompositeDisposable();
        mPagination = PublishProcessor.create();
    }

 @Override
    public void fetchProductByType() {
        if (mProductsView == null)
            return;

        mIsProductsLoading = true;
        mProductsView.startLookUp();

        final Disposable disposable = mService.fetchProductByType(mPagination, createProductRequest(), new Service.ResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object response) {
                mPageNumber = mPageNumber + FETCH_ROW_COUNT;
                mIsProductsLoading = false;

                ResultSet<Product> listResult = (ResultSet<Product>) response;

                // Tell paginator that we got less data than
                // requested, so no more further calls
                if (listResult.getData().size() < FETCH_ROW_COUNT) {
                    Logger.logE(ProductPresenter.class.getName(), "onComplete===");
                    mPagination.onComplete();
                }

                mProductsView.lookUpCompleted();
                mProductsView.onRemoteDataReceived(listResult.getData());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(NetworkError networkError) {


                mIsProductsLoading = false;
                mProductsView.onRemoteDataReceiveFailed(networkError.getAppErrorMessage());
            }
        });

        mSubscriptions.add(disposable);
    }
```

**Service Class**

```
 public Disposable fetchProductByType(PublishProcessor<ProductRequest> paginate, ProductRequest requestBody, final ResponseCallback callback) {
        final Disposable subscribe = paginate
                .onBackpressureDrop()
                .flatMap(new Function<ProductRequest, Publisher<ResultSet<Product>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Publisher<ResultSet<Product>> apply(@NonNull ProductRequest page) throws Exception {
                        return networkService.fetchProductByType(page).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, Publisher<? extends ResultSet<Product>>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Publisher<? extends ResultSet<Product>> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                return null;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Consumer<ResultSet<Product>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(ResultSet<Product> productResultSet) throws Exception {
                        callback.onSuccess(productResultSet);
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        handleError(callback, throwable);
                    }
                });

        paginate.onNext(requestBody);
        return subscribe;
    }
```

**End Point**

```
   @POST(RemoteConstants.METHOD_PRODUCT_BY_TYPE)
   Flowable<ResultSet<Product>> fetchProductByType(@Body ProductRequest requestBody);
```

**ResultSet**

```
public class ResultSet<T> extends RemoteStatus {
    private List<T> data;

    private int total;

    public List<T> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

I've read through [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators) and tried to implement but couldn't make it. Pl. help me to fix this one, I'm stuck.